# Image Map functionality getting nixed by SOMETHING

Tags: html, imagemap

I'm designing a site for a friend, and am almost done, but for SOME reason, my image map references are getting nixed by something.  I've looked high and low, taken out references to jQuery, CSS, JS scripts, and am at my wits end as to why it won't work.  It is at http://www.toddwhittle.com/jp.  If you click on "Clients" and use the right scroll bar to go down where you see "Promos/Commercials/Politicals", the image will pop up above the list of clients.  There is where I have several YouTube links that should pop up in a new window.  But no joy.  Can someone please help?

Thanks in advance,
TW

Comment: No, I don’t see “Promos/Commercials/Politicals” on the page, and I have no idea of what you mean by “the image” that “will pop up”. The page contains several HTML syntax errors.

Answer (score 0):

When imagemaps don't work it is almost without exception because the map-bound image is not the top layer.

Here's your layout:

```
<dl class="folio">
    <dt></dt>
    <dd class="dt">
        <div id="img1" style="opacity:0;"> ... </div>
        <div id="img2" style="opacity:0;"> ... </div>
        ...
        <div id="img8" class="active"> ... </div>            
        <div id="img9" style="opacity:0;"> ... </div>
    </dd>
</dl>
```

The imagemap is in the "active" one. All these are `position: absolute` from css and are layered one on top of the other.

Setting the `opacity: 0` does not make the browser ignore something - it just makes it transparent. The imagemap is therefore underneath `img9` which is rendered later.

The easy solution is just to use `display: none` instead of `opacity: 0` to conceal the inactive layers. Alternatively you can set `z-index: 10` (or something higher than any others you may be using) on the active layer to ensure it is on top.